# Rounded skewed top shape in css

Tags: css, transform, css-shapes

I need to make a div that looks like this:

[image: skewed top with rounded corners]

With text in the middle in css. I tried looking at transforms and other 3d stuff, but I couldn't figure it out, especially without ruining the text.

Comment: post what you tryed..or make a Fiddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a skewed Y pseudo element as a background of the element. This won't affect the content :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #FFD505;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

- The `div` has overflow:hidden so that the overflowing parts of the pseudo-element are hidden.
- The pseudo element has a negative `z-index` so it stacks behind the content of the `div`
- The `transform-origin` is set to `0 0` so that top left of the skewed pseudo element doesn't move.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I haven't thought of splitting it up. It works great and and easy to apply other situtations

Answer (score 1):

you could use a skew'ed pseudo element for this, which ensures the text won't be skewd as well:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  background: tomato;
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">hello
</div>
```